# On what date was a coupon payment last date? would it always be before maturity date?

Tags: payment, maturity

For example, the corporate bonds pay a semi-annual coupon at the rate of 6.9% p.a. and mature on 15/April/2020.

And the value of the bonds recorded in that bank's balance sheet was 4790 as at 31/December/2016.

What will be the last coupon payment date for the bonds?

Answer (score 3):

Bonds with semi-annual interest payments have payments made every 6 months. Unless explicitly defined otherwise, the first payment will be made 6 months after the issuance and every 6 months after that (some bonds have the first interest payment immediately and the last interest payment is made the period before the maturity date). The final interest payment will be paid at maturity, along with the face value of the bond. In this case, that will be April 15, 2020.